# Why are sets in many programming languages not really sets?

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages, set, logic

In several programming languages there are Set collections which are supposed to be  implementations of the mathematical concept of a finite set.

However, this is not necessarily true, for example in `C#` and `Java`, both implementations of `HashSet<T>` allow you to add any `HashSet<T>` collection as a member of itself. Which by the modern definition of a mathematical set is not allowed.

**Background:**

According to naive set theory, the definition of a set is:

> A set is a collection of distinct objects.

However, this definition lead famously to [Russel's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) as well as other paradoxes. For convenience, Russel's Paradox is:

> Let R be the set of all sets that are not members of themselves. If R
>   is not a member of itself, then its definition dictates that it must
>   contain itself, and if it contains itself, then it contradicts its own
>   definition as the set of all sets that are not members of themselves.

So according to modern set theory (See: [ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)), the definition of a set is:

> A set is a collection of distinct objects, none of which is the set
>   itself.

Specifically, this is a result of the [axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

***Well so what? What are the implications of this? Why is this question on StackOverflow?***

One of the implications of Russel's Paradox is that *not all collections are sets*. Additionally, this was the point where mathematicians dropped the definition of a set as being the usual English definition. So I believe this question has a lot of weight when it comes to programming language design in general.

**Question(s):**

So why would programming languages, who in some form, use these principles in their very design just ignore it in the implementation of the Set in their languages libraries?

Secondly, is this a common occurrence with other implementations of mathematical concepts?

Perhaps I'm being a bit nit picky, but if these are to be true implementations of Sets, then why would part of the very definition be ignored?

**Update**

**Addition of C# and Java code snippets exemplifying behavior:**

**Java Snippet:**

```
Set<Object> hashSet = new HashSet<Object>();
hashSet.add(1);
hashSet.add("Tiger");
hashSet.add(hashSet);
hashSet.add('f');

Object[] array = hashSet.toArray();
HashSet<Object> hash = (HashSet<Object>)array[3];

System.out.println("HashSet in HashSet:");       
for (Object obj : hash)
    System.out.println(obj);

System.out.println("\nPrinciple HashSet:");
for (Object obj : hashSet)
    System.out.println(obj);
```

**Which prints out:**

```
HashSet in HashSet:
f
1
Tiger
[f, 1, Tiger, (this Collection)]

Principle HashSet:
f
1
Tiger
[f, 1, Tiger, (this Collection)]
```

**C# Snippet:**

```
HashSet<object> hashSet = new HashSet<object>();
hashSet.Add(1);
hashSet.Add("Tiger");
hashSet.Add(hashSet);
hashSet.Add('f');

object[] array = hashSet.ToArray();
var hash = (HashSet<object>)array[2];

Console.WriteLine("HashSet in HashSet:");
foreach (object obj in hash)
     Console.WriteLine(obj);

Console.WriteLine("\nPrinciple HashSet:");
foreach (object obj in hashSet)
     Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

**Which prints out:**

```
HashSet in HashSet:
1
Tiger
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Object]
f

Principle HashSet:
1
Tiger
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Object]
f
```

**Update 2**

In regards to **Martijn Courteaux**'s second point which was that it could be done in the name of computational efficiency:

I made two test collections in C#. They were identical, except in the Add method of one of the them - I added the following check: `if (this != obj)` where `obj` is the item being added to the collection.

I clocked both of them separately where they were to add 100,000 random integers:

**With Check:** ~ 28 milliseconds

**Without Check:** ~ 21 milliseconds

This is a fairly significant performance jump.

Comment: It may surprise you to learn that a computer's concept of numbers does not include Cantor's infinities, either.  Computers are finite; math is not.

Comment: "A set is a collection of distinct objects, none of which is the set itself." if your set is S = HashSet<T>, you can't add it to the HashSet, because it's type is not T. The definition doesn't say that an element of a set can't be a set, it just says that a set can't contain itself.

Comment: @Save A `Set<Object>` can contain itself because `Set<Object>` is a subtype of `Object`. Only in languages without subtyping (or more generally in languages where `Set`s of different types don't have a common supertype) would the type system prevent sets containing themselves.

Comment: @stark: Of course. However, however, this is concerning the implementation of a **finite** set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Programming language sets really aren't like ZFC sets, but for quite different reasons than you suppose:

1. You can't form a set by comprehension (i.e. set of all objects such that ...). Note that this already blocks all (I believe) naive set theory paradoxes, so they are irrelevant.
2. They usually can't be infinite.
3. There exist objects which aren't sets (in ZFC there are *only* sets).
4. They are usually mutable (i.e. you can add/remove elements to/from the set).
5. The objects they contain can be mutable.

So the answer to

> So why would programming languages, who in some form, use these principles in their very design just ignore it in the implementation of the Set in their languages libraries?

is that the languages *don't* use these principles.

Comment: Slight quibble with #1: You can form the set of all objects *in an existing set* (I don't know Java/C#, but something like `set.filter(predicate)`), which mirrors ZFC's Axiom of Comprehension (and hence blocks the paradoxes).  But yes, programming languages do not found themselves (directly) on ZFC.

Comment: @AntalS-Z, I believe that corresponds to the Axiom (schema) of Separation, not of Comprehension.  ZFC does not allow (unrestricted) Comprehension.

Comment: @ibid: You're right, of course.  I had a brain fart yesterday.  As you say, it's separation (aka *restricted* comprehension).

Comment: In the end, this answers the question in the best way - it highlights the fact that computer scientists often have to make choices based on the reality that machines are finite, what's pragmatic, etc. Ultimately, these choices typically lead to poor proxies of ideas from pure mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for C#, but as far as Java is concerned a set is a set. If you look at [the javadoc for the Set interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), you will see (emphasis mine):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. **A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.**

Whether the prohibition is actively enforced is unclear (adding a HashSet to itself does not throw any exceptions for example), but at least it is clearly documented that you should not try because the behaviour would then be unspecified.

Comment: HashSet allows it, though the documentation says it doesn't. It even has a special clause in the `toString` method that makes it say `(this set)` rather than going into infinite recursion.

Comment: I updated my question with some code snippets. As @Ghostkeeper said, it seems that the documentation doesn't follow through.

Comment: @DerekW the documentation stipulates the contract of the interface and states that if you don't follow that contract, the behaviour is unspecified. I don't see why the fact that it is not explicitly enforced is a problem: it is the programmer's responsibility to follow the rules governing the objects he uses. It is the same in maths, [you can prove that 1=2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#All_numbers_equal_all_other_numbers) if you don't follow the rules...

Comment: @assylias Excellent point. I just thought that HashSet would explicitly enforce it since it implements that interface and is part of the official java.util package. I'm now leaning towards the idea that the self-add check was excluded for performance purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think that this is because of some reasons:

1. For very specific programming purposes, you might want to create a set that contains itself. When you are doing this, you are not really caring about what a set mathematically means and you just want to enjoy the functionality a `Set` offers: *"Adding"* elements to the set without creating duplicate entries. (I have to be honest I can't think of a situation where you want to do that.)
2. For performance purposes. The chance you want to use a Set and let it contain itself is very very rare. So, it would be a waste of computing power, energy, time, performance and environmental health to check each time you try to add an element if it would be the set itself.

Comment: I did a performance comparison in regards to your second point (see my updated question). It may be the case that it was done in the name of performance.

Answer (score 0):

In java the set is mathematical set. You can insert objects, but only one can be in the set. Information from javadoc about set:

> "A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction."

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/